# Optimal data structure for binary data/Java

Tags: java, data-structures, binary, import, export

I have several input formats mostly restricted to geotiff and some proprietary binary formats. I import them into my program and then need to export them into various other data formats (also binary) but as two dimensional arrays.

Currently I hold the data after importing them into my program as a byte array. I also need to perform search and replace on element of this data. Is the byte array the best data structure  for this sort of application ?

Summary - all of my input formats are binary(geotiff and proprietary) and all of my export formats are binary(two dimensional arrays). In between import and export I need to do some search and replace. Is byte array the best data structure for this sort of application ?

Comment: Are you searching and replacing byte sequences, or something different? Without knowing that, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @KilianFoth - I search and replace byte sequences.

Comment: Then holding bytes in memory is a reasonable thing to do. (If you need to replace sequences with sequences of a different length, then an *array* may be less workable than a dynamic data structure, though.)

Comment: @KilianFoth - replaced sequences are also of same length. So shall I delete my question or leave it ? Since it looks like you answered it.

Comment: It's perfectly permissible to answer your own question and even to accept it. Why not try it out? The point if this site is to generate a repo of valuable answers, not to boost anyone's ego.

Comment: @KilianFoth - I will just wait it out for a couple of days to encourage others. If no answer I will answer it myself. Yes ?

Comment: There is no need to keep all the data in a temporary buffer to search for a sequence within - search and replace can be done on a stream, dumping processed data on offline storage. You only need a temporary buffer if you need a random access to its elements. Do you need to access random columns or rows during procesing?

Comment: @Basilevs - Yes I do need to access random columns/rows. Please go ahead and write up the answer.